# difference between solaris sparc and solaris x86

Tags: solaris-10

I have a solaris sparc machine ..  suppose if I build any application on solaris sparc machine then will that application will run on the X86 machine as well or I need to build again onn X86 machine ? I tried to search solution on google but didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the applications from source. The SPARC and x86 CPU instruction sets are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build this application again. 
General the application has the different deal with the SPARC or X86 CPU .

Answer (score 0):

Solaris x86 for Intel processor
Soalris SPARC for SUN
[More info](http://chungculinhdamhh3.blogspot.com/)